# When to use Swift’s fatalError(), precondition(), or assertion() functions?

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, uikit, runtime-error

I’m trying to determine the use-case for the Swift halting functions when reaching an irrecoverable problem. When should `precondition()` be used in comparison to `fatalError()`?

I have read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/debugging_and_reflection) and it seems that the only advantage to using `precondition()` is some optimization when creating an `-unchecked` build, but upon reaching that code without satisfying the precondition, the documentation states this is a serious programming error. What type of programming error would cause this code to be reached without satisfying the precondition? Compared to one that would be more appropriately handled by `fatalError()`? Compared to `assert()`?

Here are use-cases I currently have for each type:

---

**assert()**

```
var coreDataContainer: CoreDataContainer?
...

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    assert(coreDataContainer != nil, "CoreDataContainer property not set")
    ...
}
```

---

**precondition()**

```
var headerSize: CGSize?
...

override func prepare() {
    super.prepare()

    precondition(headerSize != nil, "Header size not set. Header size must be set by client before layout occurs.")
    ...
}
```

---

**fatalError()**

```
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController?
...

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    if let frc = self._fetchedResultsController {
        return frc.sections!.count
    }

    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    guard let sections = self._fetchedResultsController?.sections else {
        fatalError("NSFetchedResultsController sections are nil. Expected section number \(section).")
    }
    ...
}
```

I expect that a user will not reach these calls.
Are any of these examples a bad choice?

Comment: You should consider informing the user that a fatal error has occurred when forcefully exiting the app